# Find property value in array of objects (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, iteration

I have below array of objects. I want to check what errorCode value is present in `objArray`.

```
var objArr = [
  {
  "7364234": "hsjd",
  "errorCode": "400"
  },
  {
  "12345": "jd",
  "errorCode": "500-001"
  }
]
```

Below is the solution that finds the key `errorCode` is present in an array of objects or not. If I do a console.log as shown below, I get the desired results.

```
const contains = (string) =>
  objArr.findIndex(
    // Is the string contained in the object keys?
    obj => Object.keys(obj).includes(string)
  ) !== -1

console.log(contains('errorCode')) // returns true
console.log(contains('spaghetti')) // returns false
```

But I want to know what value of errorCode is present in the `objArray`. for e.g. i want to find out if `errorCode: "500-001"` is present in `objArray`. How can I get this result? Can someone please suggest?

Comment: Welcome to SO! FYI `includes` is better than `findIndex` if you're just throwing away the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` as follows.

```js
var objArr = [
  {
  "7364234": "hsjd",
  "errorCode": "400"
  },
  {
  "12345": "jd",
  "errorCode": "500-001"
  }
];

const contains = (keyVal) => objArr.some(({ errorCode }) => errorCode.includes(keyVal));
console.log(contains("500"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each element and check whether it contains the code you're looking for:

```
function hasErrorCode( errorCode ) {
    var r = false; // assume
    objArr.forEach( function( o ) {
        if ( o.errorCode == errorCode ) {
            r = true;
        }
    } );
    return r;
}

console.log( hasErrorCode( '400' ) ); // true
console.log( hasErrorCode( 'asdfasdf' ) ); // false
```

This could be made more efficient by using a standard `for` loop, and using `break` to exit when the code is found.